# Android notifications not work when sent through Amazon SNS

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

We have been sending messages through Amazon SNS and Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) to an Android device. This is the raw SNS json message we are entering into the SNS send message function:

```
{
    "GCM": "{\"data\":{\"someData\":62},\"notification\":{\"body\":\"Body message\",\"title\":\"A Title\"}}",
    "default": "My default message"
}
```

For some reason the Notification section with it's `title` and `body` appear to be ignored. No notification is appearing on the device.

Can anyone confirm that notifications can be sent through SNS or is there (as we suspect) some limitation where only the `data{...}` part of the json is understood?

Comment: Here's a good tutorial: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-gcm.html

Comment: Yep.Seen that. But it doesn't answer the question about the notification node in the JSON above.

Answer (score 4):

I have updated the json format and i get the notification sent from SNS on my android device.

```
{
"GCM": "{ \"notification\": { \"body\": \"hello....\", \"title\": \"title123\" } }"
}
```

[image: SNS Notification on Android]

Comment: Is that due to SNS still working with GCM and google migrating towards FCM?

Answer (score 1):

Notifications will not show up in the tray if the app happens to be running in the foreground. However, the data should still be available. Here are the docs: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages